# What is the best way to pass a parameter from views into an anchor tag?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm building a dashboard that has a button on a sidebar that allows a user to update their data. Which currently looks like this:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'form-update' pk=id %}"> Questionnaire </a>
```

I'm trying to connect that `id` field to my `views.py`:

```
def dashboard(request):
    user = request.user
    account = 0
    id = Form.objects.filter(author=user,account=account).values('id').get('id')
    context = {
        'id':id
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html',context)
```

url pattern:

```
path('update/<int:pk>', FormUpdateView.as_view(),name='form-update')
```

I'm not sure the best way to send this data to the href tag?

**EDIT**
It seems to be an issue because this dashboard html file is a base HTML file that I use with other templates. If I load the data in a child template than it loads fine, just not at the parent html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles across this, the issue actually arose from passing a variable to a base HTML file. In this case, you have to create a file in your app (`context_processors.py`) then create a function in there:

```
def add_variable_to_context(request):
user = request.user
account = 0
pk = Form.objects.filter(author=user,account=account).values('id').last().get('id')

return {
    'id': pk
}
```

Then register this py file in `settings.py` context_processors.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'dashboard.context_processors.add_variable_to_context',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

You can then call that variable in the normal fashion.

```
 <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'form-update' pk=id %}">Questionnaire</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**views.py:**

```
def dashboard(request):
        user = request.user
        account = 0
        id = Form.objects.get(author=user,account=account)
        context = {
            'id':id.id
        }
        return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html',context)
```

**urls.py:**

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'form-update' pk=id %}"> Questionnaire </a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was lazy with the query (which I just edited) but that's not the issue. It doesn't pass the data properly to the html. That's the issue I'm facing.